"20 minutes cooking time" — Why is this phrase correct? I think it must have an apostrophe after "minutes"
collinsdictionary.com:
(1) Leave the vegetables to steam over the rice for the 20 minutes cooking time.
As far as I understand:
"Time" is a head noun.
"Cooking" is an adjective.
"20 minutes" is the noun phrase which modifiers "cooking time".
Why is it correct to use the measure expression "20 minutes" as a modifier?
my variants:
(2) Leave the vegetables to steam over the rice for the 20 minutes' cooking time. — (with the apostrophe)
(3) Leave the vegetables to steam over the rice for the 20 minutes of cooking time.
(4) Leave the vegetables to steam over the rice for the 20-minute cooking time.
I understand why (2), (3) and (4) are correct, but I don't understand why (1) is correct.
P.S.: There is a thread with the same sentence, but it has a somewhat different question.

You have to reverse the order when you substitute an apostrophe for "of". e.g. "The feathers of the birds" = "the birds' feathers." So if (3) is correct then (2) cannot be correct.

No, cooking cannot be an adjective in cooking time because the time is not cooking and because it cannot be modified by adverbs.

@tchrist britannica.com: "cooking" in "Cooking time is about 20 minutes" is an adjective.

Your link leads to this: Although the corpus examples were extracted using an algorithm and have not been editorially reviewed, we hope that you find the extra context a helpful addition to the main dictionary entry.

@HitenStyle Following your logic, (2) is correct because "the 20 minutes' cooking time" = "the cooking time of 20 minutes".

@Loviii I'm sorry, but that is utterly incorrect, a model almost 100 years out of date. It's provably and inarguably a different part of speech that happens to be acting in the grammatical role of a modifier in the noun phrase. Ancient models of analysis dating from the work of Latin grammarian Aelius Donatus during the fourth century are of no use whatsoever in modern analysis, particularly of English. That primitive system has been long ago abandoned by modern linguists because it is useless and wrong for describing the relationships between syntactic constituents.

Notice that that "dictionary" also pretends that some is somehow an "adjective". It very most certainly is not! It's a certain subtype of determiners. Please see Wikipedia's article on Noun Phrases for how NPs are currently analysed in the science of linguistics. The entire model of assigning parts of speech used in that "dictionary" is hopelessly out of date. Please do not try to use dictionaries for providing reliable grammatical information; they are not built for being able to do that.

I’m voting to close this question because it is based on the false premise that the cited example is somehow correct.

@tchrist You wrote: "Please do not try to use dictionaries for providing reliable grammatical information" This is a very strange phrase towards a non-native speaker. In order to apply linguistic tests for finding out what part of speech a word is, I must know what phrase is natural and what phrase is not. But I can only know correctness of phrases but not their naturalness - it's just impossible for me - because I'm not a native English speaker. So dictionaries (along with users' answers and comments as yours) are one of the things to me for getting information, including lexical categories

@tchrist As far as I understood, you voted to close the question because you consider "the 20 minutes cooking time" (without the apostrophe) incorrect. But if you follow the link I gave in the post-scriptum section and read the comments there, you'll see some users disagree with you.

Yes, because measure phrases involving units that are acting as modifiers in English  need to be in the singular. Compare taking a five minute walk with spending five minutes quickly walking or spending five minutes of quick walking.

Related: tomorrow morning vs. tomorrow's morning and two year or two year's and Two weeks' overdue


... the twenty-minute cooking time

is correct and grammatical.
Compare:

... has a nine-month gestation period.

The plural version

... the twenty-minutes cooking time

is marginal but might be justifiable in context, as alluding to, or even quoting, the specific length of time called for in a recipe:

Put on the burner at medium and cook for 20 minutes.

Something like this:

We find the recommended 20-minute cooking time too little and would  double that.
We find the stated 20 minutes cooking time too little and would  double that.

It is as if there are quotation marks surrounding 20 minutes.
Even quoted phrases should be syntax-compatible with the sentence into which they're placed, but the rules are often relaxed when the violation is minor and it doesn't undermine the sense.

I'd still do either "We find the stated cooking time of 20 minutes too little and would double that" or else "We find the stated 20 minutes❜ cooking time too little and would double that."

@tchrist   I'm not advocating, just trying to explain what I think is going on there.

Simply put, minutes is the plural of minute, there are 20 of them in this case. Similar to "place the ball 20 feet away", there is no suggestion that "feet" should somehow be possessive and have an apostrophe s.
Minutes' is the possessive, as in "a few minutes' walk"

In "the 20 minutes cooking time", the NP "20 minutes" is the internal modifier of the nominal "cooking time". In "place the ball 20 feet away", the NP "20 feet" is an external complement of the intransitive preposition "away". So these two phrases are not comparable at all.

"a few minutes' walk" — you used an apostrophe here. In the original post, I wrote I understand why the analogue with the apostrophe is correct. But I'd like to know why the phrase without one (namely, "the 20 minutes cooking time") is correct too.

@Loviii It is not correct. It must be "the 20-minute cooking time" just as it must be "a five-minute walk". You can't have a plural unit in a measure phrase that's modifying another NP in English. That's why it can only ever be "a six-foot man" never *"a six-feet man". I know this seems strange, but it is so. It's in keeping with the general principle that (most) nouns used as attributive modifiers in English are normally restricted to the singular.

@tchrist That is not true in BrE: the drugs policy or the drugs war. There are others like that.

@Lambie You exaggerate and misapply what I said: I've never met any “six-feet tall men” in the UK, and neither shall you.  Once again, with stress, so you can read it again: MOST nouns used as attributive modifiers in English are NORMALLY restricted to the singular. This general rule of thumb, especially of units, is not suspended in any region populated by native speakers: the "most" and "normally" certainly still apply, whatever "women posters" might otherwise claim. <--- Notice how women is plural there. The rare exceptions differ from one locale to another, that's all.

@tchrist I  agree with the units bit. not: "It's in keeping with the general principle that (most) nouns used as attributive modifiers in English are normally restricted to the singular." https://www.theguardian.com/media/mind-your-language/2012/jul/05/mind-your-language-nouns Just one bit from that article: There's not much in the way of "official" guidance. The Chicago Manual of Style has it thus: "[...] an attributive becomes conventional in the singular (toy store), and sometimes in the plural (ladies room). Often we choose by ear and it doesn't matter (employee lounge, employees lounge)."
